# Mapster.Tool fails generating mapper

Tags: c#, mapster

Mapster.Tool fails to generate any code.
The problem seems to be a class derived from CosmosClient - which i get from a nuget package.

I get this exception:

> Cannot find library: Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client
> Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client, Version=3.16.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.
> at system.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
> at Mapster.Tool.Extensions.Scan(CodeGenerationConfig config, Assembly assembly) in D:\git\Mapster\src\Mapster.Tool\Extensions.cs:line 177
> at Mapster.Tool.Program.GenerateModels(ModelOptions opt) in D:\git\Mapster\src\Mapster.Tool\Program.cs:line 123
> at CommandLine.ParserResultExtensions.WithParsed[T](ParserResult`1 result, Action`1 action)
> at Mapster.Tool.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\git\Mapster\src\Mapster.Tool\Program.cs:line 17
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client, Version=3.16.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.
> File name: 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client, Version=3.16.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Everything works fine when i disable the mapster build target.
Also, Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client.dll exists in the target directory.

Soooo.. what am i doing wrong?
I dont understand why mapster cant load that assembly.
There also seems to be no way to make mapster ignore that class.

Heres the code.

```cs
using Mapster;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using System;

namespace MapsterTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbClient : CosmosClient
    {
        public ApplicationDbClient() : base("ConnectinString")
        { }
    }

    [AdaptTo(typeof(MyModelDto)), GenerateMapper]
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyModelDto
    {
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

my csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Mapster" Version="7.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos" Version="3.16.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Mapster" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" Command="dotnet tool restore" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" Command="dotnet mapster model -a &quot;$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).dll&quot;" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" Command="dotnet mapster extension -a &quot;$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).dll&quot;" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" Command="dotnet mapster mapper -a &quot;$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).dll&quot;" />
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Generated Include="**\*.g.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Models\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="CleanGenerated">
    <Delete Files="@(Generated)" />
  </Target>
  
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was a problem with multiple runtime assemblies.
See [this github issue](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/issues/319).

This has been fixed with mapster.tool version 8.2.0